# How to propagate value onto n previous rows of pandas series

Tags: python, pandas

Let's assume I have a Pandas series like below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
x = pd.Series(np.concatenate([[0] * 20, [1], [0] * 34, [1], [0] * 3]))
```

Now I'd like to propagate those values of 1 onto n previous rows, for example 5 (including the one with the value of 1 already). So the expected output would be like below:

```
x_out = pd.Series(np.concatenate([[0] * 16, [1] * 5, [0] * 30, [1] * 5, [0] * 3]))
```

How can I do that?

Comment: depending on what you really want to do, using a window function (e.g. max) could lead to the desired output in a way open for customization. otherwise something like ansevs answer.

Answer (score 1):

We can convert to `NaN` the values ​​that are not `one` with [`Series.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) then fill with [`Series.bfill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25.0/reference/api/pandas.Series.bfill.html) and finally return the `0` with [`Series.fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html)

```
 n = 5
 x_out = x.where(x.eq(1)).bfill(limit = n-1).fillna(0,downcast = 'int64')
 #x_out = x.where(x.eq(1)).bfill(limit = n-1).fillna(0).astype(int)
 #alternative
 #x_out = x.mask(x.eq(0)).bfill(limit = n-1).fillna(0,downcast = 'int64')
print(x_out)
```

**Output**

```
0     0
1     0
2     0
3     0
4     0
5     0
6     0
7     0
8     0
9     0
10    0
11    0
12    0
13    0
14    0
15    0
16    1
17    1
18    1
19    1
20    1
21    0
22    0
23    0
24    0
25    0
26    0
27    0
28    0
29    0
30    0
31    0
32    0
33    0
34    0
35    0
36    0
37    0
38    0
39    0
40    0
41    0
42    0
43    0
44    0
45    0
46    0
47    0
48    0
49    0
50    0
51    1
52    1
53    1
54    1
55    1
56    0
57    0
58    0
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `pandas.Series.rolling`:

```
x_new = x[::-1].rolling(5, min_periods=0).max()[::-1]
```

Output:

```
x_out.eq(x_new).all()
# True
```

Comment: Unfortunetely, it fails with two values of 1 in range of 5 rows as it would be summed to 2 which is not desirable

Comment: @jakes I've edited `sum` as `max`. Can you check once again?